# Django rest framework not refreshing template changes

Tags: python, html, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I was trying to update my django rest framework browsable api template, initially trying to change the theme and afterwards changing the navbar branding text, but, after creating the `rest_framework/api.html` file for the first time, the changes got stuck and the initial changes will not either update nor delete. I've tried deleting the whole `proj/app/templates/rest_framework` directory, but the changes are still there. I also deleted my browser's cache and cloudflare's cache, restarted Apache 2, and even restarted the server.

This is my `app` directory:

```
website
├── __init__.py
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── locale
│   └── (more folders)
├── models.py
├── static
│   └── (more folders)
├── templates
│   ├── anime
│   │   ├── detail.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── (here was the rest_framework directory with the api.html file)
│   ├── footer.html
│   ├── imports.html
│   ├── navbar.html
│   └── website
│       ├── index.html
│       └── welcome.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

My current `api.html` looks like this:

```html
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block bootstrap_theme %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/static/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="nofollow" href="#">
        My Project
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```

In the browsable api, however, the navbar title is still **Django REST framework** and in the `header` tag I get:

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
    <title>Detail Api – Django REST framework</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/static/rest_framework/css/prettify.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/static/rest_framework/css/default.css">

    <!-- here are the changes I made in the initial version of the file -->
    <style>long style in the initial version of the file</style>
</head>
```

Edit: I've checked if there is any file in the project folder or in the venv folder containing `<style>pre` where it could be cached using `grep -Rnwli './' -e '<style>pre'` but it shows no results. I've also ran a `curl` command to localhost from the server to check if this was a Cloudflare cache problem (`curl -H "Host: api.example.com" --insecure https://localhost/path`) but it is still returning the wrong version of the template.

Edit 2: I've ran the server using 'python3 manage.py runserver' instead of using apache2 and the old version is still there. The problem is in the django project, not cloudflare nor apache.

Comment: Maybe check the `STATIC_ROOT` setting in your Django settings. Your static files will be in that folder. If you want to update it, run `python manage.py collectstatic`. Have you tried to do this?

Comment: Yes, I've did this multiple times. I think that's not the problem because it's a template, not a static file and I have it in `debug = False` so the templates should reload automatically